# SalesForce SmartSync and SmartStore how to create related object on iOS

Tags: ios, salesforce

I have to create a custom object (object1) in an iOS native app which has a related object field `Contact__c`, and I have an other custom object (object2), which has an object1.

My problem:

When I create the object1, I can set the Contact__c the Id of the Contact object from SF, but when I create object2 I can't set the object1's Id because it's nil.

I can't find a solution in the documentation on how to store related object in smartstore and then sync them up with smartsync.

Is it possible to generate an Id for the local objects?

Thanks in advance!